# convergence of series from $1$ to $\infty$ of $\sin^2(n)/\sqrt{n^2+1}$.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

does this series converge??

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{\sin^2(n)}{\sqrt{n^2+1}}$$

I don't know even if this is decreasing or not.

Comment: Individual terms have a limit of $0$ since they are positive but less than $\dfrac1n$

Comment: Thanks, I really appreciate your help. Please excuse my English I'm still learning.

Comment: @O.Arcila Is it ok.

Comment: Intuitively, on average half of the terms have a numerator $\ge1/2$ regularly, and the denominators behave like $n$. Hence the series diverges like the harmonic one.

Comment: @O.Arcila You were wondering whether the sequence is decreasing: it is not.  For instance, the $n=4$ term is larger than the $n=3$ term.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we have

$$\frac{\sin^2(n)}{\sqrt{n^2+1}}\sim \frac{1-\cos(2n)}{2n}\; (n\to +\infty)$$

$\sum \frac{\cos(2n)}{n}$ is convergent by Abel's Rule.

$\sum \frac{1}{n}$ diverges.

thus, your positive series diverges and

$$\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin^2(n)}{\sqrt{n^2+1}}=+\infty.$$

Comment: The importance of the original series being positive is pretty subtle here, you should probably call more explicit attention to why it's necessary.

Comment: Hello please can you elaborate about the use of Abel's Rule. Thanks.

Comment: I think that instead of Abel's Rule is Dirichlet's?